# Работа скрипта после загрузки данных из базы

Tags: javascript, select

Скрипт меняет ширину блока span в зависимости от текста, который там находится, а текст получает из select. проблема в том, что пункты select у меня выводятся из базы и selected='selected' устанавливается в зависимости от переменной. Только скрипт значение поля option selected='selected' в span не заносит. Как можно его изменить, чтобы он это делал? Сам скрипт

```
$(window).load(function() {
        var select = $('.select');
        var search = $('.search');

        var wi = search.innerWidth();
        select.width(wi);

        $('.select').change(function(){

            var name = $('.select :selected').text();
            search.text(name);
            var wi = search.innerWidth();
            select.width(wi);
        })});
```

Пример его [работы](http://jsfiddle.net/satantx/u0cazrog/)

html:

```
<div class='search_box'>
                <form name='search_form' action='?view=magazine_rubric' method='GET'>
                    <div class='button_field'>
                        <input name='submit' type='submit' value='' title='Найти'>
                    </div>                    <div class='select_box'>
                        <span class='search'>Всё</span>
                        <select title='Где искать' name='select' class='select'>
                            <option  value='all'>Всё</option>
                            <option selected='selected' value='1'>Мужские статьи</option>
                            <option value='6'>Женские статьи</option>
                            <option value='11'>Общие статьи</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class='search_field'>
                        <input name='query' type='search' placeholder='Поиск по журналу' onfocus='this.select();' value=''>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Сервер выставляет selected='selected'. По умолчанию он стоит в опции "Всё". Если делать выбор вручную, то скрипт выставляет текст опции в , а если selected='selected' выставлено при загрузке странице сервером, то текст так и остаётся по умолчанию, а не меняется на тот, который обозначен selected='selected'. Но по факту сервер выставляет всё верно - в коде странице проверял. Если так понятнее)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень внятно вы вопрос сформулировали.. [Это то,что вам нужно](http://jsfiddle.net/u0cazrog/1/)?

Comment: Darth, спасибо, но не то. Дополнил вопрос, если так понятнее

Comment: Нет, всё равно непонятно. Я так понял, что у вас есть вот этот вот select, в котором есть selected option, и вы хотите, чтобы при загрузке страницы просходило тоже самое, что происходит, когда какая-то опция выбирается вручную пользователем? Если так, то что не так с моим вариантом? [Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/u0cazrog/2/) я немного переделал

Comment: Darth, спасибо! Так работает! А я уже начал решать этот вопрос с помощью php)